# I am deploying my symfony 5 application. What do I forget to do?

Tags: php, symfony, autoload, deploying

In development mode, when i execute this command 
**symfony server:start -d**
The application works verry well.
But when i writes the http://localhost/wafrica2/public/app_dev.php url, this error points out.

**Warning: require(C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\public/../app/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\public\app_dev.php on line 21**

[This is autoload.php file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bOXq.png)

It is the same error that arises when I upload to  **Infomaniak server** after having set the file .env

[this image shows the error as returned by the infomaniak server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZwvg.png)

APP_ENV=prod
DATABASE_URL=...

The .htaccess file

```html
# Use the front controller as index file. It serves as a fallback solution when
# every other rewrite/redirect fails (e.g. in an aliased environment without
# mod_rewrite). Additionally, this reduces the matching process for the
# start page (path "/") because otherwise Apache will apply the rewriting rules
# to each configured DirectoryIndex file (e.g. index.php, index.html, index.pl).
 DirectoryIndex app.php

# By default, Apache does not evaluate symbolic links if you did not enable this
# feature in your server configuration. Uncomment the following line if you
# install assets as symlinks or if you experience problems related to symlinks
# when compiling LESS/Sass/CoffeScript assets.
# Options FollowSymlinks

# Disabling MultiViews prevents unwanted negotiation, e.g. "/app" should not resolve
# to the front controller "/app.php" but be rewritten to "/app.php/app".
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Determine the RewriteBase automatically and set it as environment variable.
    # If you are using Apache aliases to do mass virtual hosting or installed the
    # project in a subdirectory, the base path will be prepended to allow proper
    # resolution of the app.php file and to redirect to the correct URI. It will
    # work in environments without path prefix as well, providing a safe, one-size
    # fits all solution. But as you do not need it in this case, you can comment
    # the following 2 lines to eliminate the overhead.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    # Sets the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header removed by apache
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect to URI without front controller to prevent duplicate content
    # (with and without `/app.php`). Only do this redirect on the initial
    # rewrite by Apache and not on subsequent cycles. Otherwise we would get an
    # endless redirect loop (request -> rewrite to front controller ->
    # redirect -> request -> ...).
    # So in case you get a "too many redirects" error or you always get redirected
    # to the start page because your Apache does not expose the REDIRECT_STATUS
    # environment variable, you have 2 choices:
    # - disable this feature by commenting the following 2 lines or
    # - use Apache >= 2.3.9 and replace all L flags by END flags and remove the
    #   following RewriteCond (best solution)
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

    # If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
    # We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]

    # Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        # When mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect of
        # the start page to the front controller explicitly so that the website
        # and the generated links can still be used.
         RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
        # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Is it possible to run a symfony 5 application without execute the symfony server:start command? I think, the response to this question can help me.
Please, can you help me?

Comment: There's no `app_dev.php` or `app/` directory in Symfony > 4. Have you created it yourself ?

Comment: Can you show your .htaccess file or your server configuration in apache? It should look something like this for Symfony 5: https://symfony.com/index.php/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html#apache-with-mod-php-php-cgi

Comment: Im deploying application in infomaniak server. So i can't get to those informations

Comment: someone reminded me that in fact there is no app_dev.php file in symfony> 4. I deleted this file, it did not solve the problem. I also note that the file autoload.php is rather in vendor

Comment: If you didn't solve this already, this is the [`index.php`](https://github.com/symfony/recipes/blob/master/symfony/framework-bundle/5.1/public/index.php) file for symfony 5. You should change references in the .htaccess file from `app.php` to `index.php` (or you can save this file as `app.php`, if you prefer). The image you show is indeed from [symfony 3.2](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/3.2/web/app_dev.php) so something is up. Do the directories `app/` or `web/` exist?

Answer (score 1):

In Symfony >4, there is no app.php nor app_dev.php.
The environnement is defined in the .env file by the `APP_ENV = prod` or `APP_ENV=dev` for example.
If you have installed the web profiler bundle, you should have the debug toolbar while in dev. You may have to install the apache-pack bundle to make it work.

The web server root is in `public` folder. When you launch the server, the console should display the URL where your app is available.

Comment: I delete those two files and this is the new error   :   Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at postmaster@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: When i read a .htaccess file, a se that there a app.php argument. So those file shoud exist in public folder

Comment: Did you start from a blank Symfony5 project ? This is weird. In a Symfony4 project, I have no mention of app.php

Comment: The command php bin/console about return 5.0.7 version of Symfony

Comment: Hi there. Ok for the version of symfony. But did you start from a new project or is it an upgrade from version 3 ?

Comment: I started with a new project

Comment: Can you try to create a new blank project and run the server:start command to check if it works ?